# How to get data using fetch API with mode 'no-cors'?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

My code looks like this. How do I read the response data?

```
var url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football';

fetch(url, {
  mode : 'no-cors'
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

[Response Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwmJu.png)

Answer (score 14):

You can't.

If the origin doesn't support CORS, you can't actually get the response data directly.  That's the whole point of `no-cors`... allowing you to use the response in certain ways, but not actually read/access the data.

Comment: I changed to jQuery ajax method with jsonp as below

   var url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football?callback=?';

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
But getting below error now.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                                       football?callback=jQuery3110607…_1478389724278&_=1478389724279:1

Comment: @AnoopMundathan Why would you do that?  This URL doesn't support JSON-P, and JSON-P is a nasty hack anyway.  You should be using CORS, but since your source doesn't support it, you're out of luck unless you proxy it server-side.

Comment: Yes, that option left now. Proxy in server side. Cheers

Answer (score -5):

Use one of below, depending what data you expect:

```
response.blob()
response.text()
response.formData()
response.json()
response.arrayBuffer()
```

Comment: This is not accurate.  It's not possible to get the data cross-origin with `no-cors`.